# Ввод данных с помощью диалога

Tags: android, eclipse

Можно ли ввести данный с помощью диалога? Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку всплывал диалог, что-то вроде "введите значение" и поле для ввода? Если можно, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
String value = input.getText();
 // Do something with value!
 }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
     // Canceled.
}
});

 alert.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

Конечно можно.

- [пример раз](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/)
- [пример два, более короткий](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog)